# Forcing the date format in a powershell DIR listing

Tags: windows, powershell, date, date-formatting

I'm trying to write an enhanced directory utility (in python) which post-processes a number of directory listings obtained via command-prompt `DIR` commands.  The issue is that I need the datetime output in a specific agnostic format of `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`.

`DIR` gives me:

```
27-Apr-17  06:18 p.m.                56 cq.bat
27-Apr-17  06:13 p.m.                27 cqr.bat
27-Apr-17  06:15 p.m.                69 cqu.bat
06-Jul-16  08:43 a.m.               164 cr.bat
15-Jun-16  12:35 p.m.                36 crb.bat
26-Mar-16  01:41 p.m.               102 cru.bat
25-May-16  04:11 p.m.                62 ct.bat
07-Mar-16  07:48 a.m.                71 ctr.bat
```

which suffers from:

- no seconds in the time
- date-time width is not necessarily fixed between PC's or locales.

Similarly `powershell dir` gives me:

```
-a----       27-Apr-17  6:13 p.m.             27 cqr.bat
-a----       27-Apr-17  6:15 p.m.             69 cqu.bat
-a----       06-Jul-16  8:43 a.m.            164 cr.bat
-a----      15-Jun-16  12:35 p.m.             36 crb.bat
-a----       26-Mar-16  2:41 p.m.            102 cru.bat
-a----       25-May-16  4:11 p.m.             62 ct.bat
-a----       07-Mar-16  8:48 a.m.             71 ctr.bat
```

Which has similar issues for me, but I'm reasoning that powershell might be a bit more flexible in the date formatting department.

I'd rather not have to save/mess with/restore the PC's date format strings.

Desired output would be:

```
2017-04-27 18:13:12             27 cqr.bat
2017-04-27 18:15:33             69 cqu.bat
2016-07-06  8:43:53            164 cr.bat
2016-06-15 12:35:22             36 crb.bat
2016-03-26 14:41:53            102 cru.bat
2016-05-25 16:11:44             62 ct.bat
2016-03-07  8:48:23             71 ctr.bat
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented, the date format is Case-Sensitive (i.e. `M` is for months, while `m` is for minutes).

To use a calculated property on this using the `-f` Format operator, you need to set a template string to format the property to insert in there.

Try

```
Get-ChildItem 'ThePath' |
Select-Object @{n='LastWriteTime';e={'{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}' -f $_.LastWriteTime}}, Length, Name
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  The date formatting is now correct, though obviously I will need to investigate PS formatting in a bit more detail.  I need the formatting to be rigid to simplify parsing the output, whereas the formatting in your answer seems to left justify it if it's going to be more than 8 characters.  Likewise, I have seen instances where the name is truncated and ellipses added, but at the moment I can't repro it.  How would I right-justify the filesize in 10 spaces?

Comment: @rossmcm It is not left-aligning, this is just the way PowerShell by default formats a table output in the console. If the Length gets many digits, the whole field width for that column is used, making it **look** like a left-align.  You may try adding `| -AutoSize`, but with long filenames it won't fit the console width and then the lines are truncated with ellipses.  Otherwise, you may like the output when piped to `| Out-GridView` better as this is a new graphic window with sizable columns.

Comment: so how do I obtain the file size as an integer and write it out with (say) a format specifier of "%10d" - which is how I would output an integer right-justified in10 spaces (in Python or Delphi).

Comment: @rossmcm The `Length` property **is** an integer number. If you want that right aligned up to 10 characters, you could do that by making another calculated property of it like: `@{n='Size';e={ "$_.Length".PadLeft(10) }}` or with `@{n='Size';e={ '{0,10}' -f $_.Length }}`

Answer (score 3):

You can use a calculated property and the ToString() method

```
Get-ChildItem $somepath | Select-Object @{n='LastWriteTime';e={$_.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")}},Length,Name
```

This will give you the 3 columns you specified. You could also take advantage of [natural line breaks](https://get-powershellblog.blogspot.com/2017/07/bye-bye-backtick-natural-line.html#:%7E:text=When%20you%20use%20a%20Natural,in%20laying%20out%20your%20code.) for readability.

```
Get-ChildItem $somepath |
    Select-Object @{n='LastWriteTime';e={$_.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")}},
                  Length,
                  Name
```

Comment: Thanks for replying @Doug.  The command: `powershell Get-ChildItem "*.txt" ^| Select-Object @{n='LastWriteTime';e={$_.LastWriteTime -f \"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS\"}},Length,Name` gives me the right files, but the date-format string appears to be ignored `11/13/2019 18:13:18 1633766 file.txt`.

Comment: Also (and this is _really_ weird) sometimes the size field in the output switches from right-justified to left-justified!

Comment: The date format string should be `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`. The casing does matter here!

Comment: I liked your comment as it made sense, however my testing shows the same regardless?  I see no difference in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS and yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss. I'm sure I'm missing something simple, can you explain it Theo? This is in ps 5.1

Comment: @DougMaurer That depends on what is set in your system's locale. On my Dutch machine `'{0:YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS}' -f (Get-Date)` returns `YYYY-09-DD 17:09:SS`. `'{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}' -f (Get-Date)` returns the correct format: `2020-09-15 17:10:15`

Comment: Ahh I didn’t even consider that. Thank you for letting me know. I’ll update my answer so others won’t make that same mistake.

Comment: @DougMaurer Also, `$_.LastWriteTime -f "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"` is not the way the `-f` Format operator works. You could change that to `$_.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")`